# Ionic 2 cannot find namespace for @types/package

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Using Ionic 2  I am trying to add Typescript definition files for [FHIR](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/). Following the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/#type-definitions) I have run the following command:

```
npm install --save @types/fhir
```

Which executes without complaint. I can see the Typescript definition file added under my `node_modules @types` folder:

[image: VS Code FHIR Types]

The editor doesn't complain when I reference the types in my component file. However, when I run `ionic serve`, I get an error displayed in the terminal:

> Cannot find namespace 'fhir'

My IDE is Visual Studio Code which I have tried restarting. I have tried deleting and re-installing the types.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {CreateReferralPage} from '../create-referral/create-referral';
import { HomeProvider } from "../../providers/home/home";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit{

  patient : fhir.Patient = {};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private homeProvider: HomeProvider) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.homeProvider.getPatientDetails().subscribe((patient : fhir.Patient) => {
      this.patient = patient;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you importing it and using it?

Comment: I have added how I am using the types. I should not need to import the types, as they were installed via npm. By default packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should have a compiled Javascript version of the index.d.ts inside the npm package. While developing you don't get any error cause Typescript uses the original definitions found inside TS files but whenever you launch the app, it will use the compiled JS files that are not found in your npm folder, thus, throwing an error.